# Java - insert "-" between contiguous digits in string

Tags: java

I am trying to create new string by inserting "-" between contiguous numbers in a string, for e.g if the input string is "bea345ful" the output string should be like "bea3-4-5ful" but if input string is "be3u4t5ful" I don't need to insert "-" since none of the digits are contiguous.

I am able to make it work with following code but it fails when there are contiguous digits at end of string for e.g. "be3u4t5f67" in that case it throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException which I understand is happening because my code is not handling this condition. Any suggestions how to fix it?

```
    public static String insertDash(String str){
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i ++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)) && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i + 1))) {
                result+=str.charAt(i) + "-";
            } else {
                result+=str.charAt(i);
            }
    } return result;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stop condition of your loop should be `i < str.length() - 1`.

Without the change, at the last iteration, `i` is equal to `str.length() - 1` and therefore accessing the element at index `str.length() - 1 + 1` (with `str.charAt(i + 1)`) triggers the exception.

After the for loop, simply append the last character to `result`.

Comment: I had tried that already and if I stop at str.length() - 1 then the code doesn't inserts a "-" between last two digits for e.g in "be3u4t5f67" it will not output expected result which is "be3u4t5f6-7" because it stopped at "6" and didn't find the next digit after it (which is "7")

Comment: It does find it because of this condition: `Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)) && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i + 1))`. Try debugging to see what else is wrong because this should really fix it :)

Comment: Consider the case where string "bedu4tdf67k", in this case the program will stop processing the string after "7" (as per i < str.length() - 1) and return the resulting string as "bedu4tdf6-7". I have been trying to debug this for a while but haven't been successful

Comment: Ah, look again at the last sentence of the answer :) "After the for loop, simply append the last character to `result`"

Comment: Glad it helped :)